# Pandas and matplotlib to create heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap

This is the code I am using to create heatmap using anaconda, python 3.5, pandas and matplotlib. the mac computer i am using has 8 GB space. The input data is in excel format as follows:.

```
Molecules   cell line 1 cell line 2 cell line 3 cell line 4 cell line 5 cell line 6 cell line 7 cell line 8 cell line 10    cell line 11    cell line 12    cell line 13    cell line 14
molecule BRCA1  3   3   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   3   2   4   2
molecule BRCA2  2   4   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2
molecule BRCA3  2   4   1   1   2   1   3   1   1   1   1   1   2
molecule BRCA4  2   4   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   2
molecule BRCA5  2   4   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   2
molecule BRCA6  2   4   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   2
.
.
.
```

The code Demo.py is found below:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import pandas as pd


Data = pd.read_excel("Demo.xlsx") #open excel file
data_value = Data.iloc[:,1:] # slice the data frame to remove first column
print(data_value) #print data frame


#high >2 fold = 1 = white = w
#low< 2 fold = 2 = green = g
#stable= 3 = blue = b
#unknown= 4 = red = r
cmapr = colors.ListedColormap(['w','g','b','r']) #set the color map to be used
cmap = plt.get_cmap(cmapr)


#create dendrograms
# -- include data frame
# -- include color map
# -- figure size IMP: Adjust as the data frame size
# -- remove the ticks from top left legend

cm = sns.clustermap(data_value,cmap = cmap, figsize=(100,120),cbar_kws={'format': '%s', 'ticks': []})

actual = Data.iloc[:,0]
final = []
lis = []
for t in cm.ax_heatmap.get_yticklabels():
    lis.append(str(t).split("'")[1])

for i in range(0,len(lis)):
    final.append(actual[int(lis[i])-1])
    print(actual[int(lis[i])-1])
#print(final)



# get the heat map to fix positions IMP: Adjust as the data frame output
hm = cm.ax_heatmap.get_position()

#fix the labels, adjust fontsize and rotation(read-ability)
plt.setp(cm.ax_heatmap.yaxis.get_majorticklabels(), fontsize=8, rotation = 0)
plt.setp(cm.ax_heatmap.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), fontsize=15, rotation = 0)

#fix the heatmap size manually.
cm.ax_heatmap.set_position([hm.x0, hm.y0, hm.width*0.25, hm.height])

#get dendograph position and fix it(enlarge it)
# -- For column
col = cm.ax_col_dendrogram.get_position()
cm.ax_col_dendrogram.set_position([col.x0, col.y0, col.width*0.25, col.height*0.7]) #col.width*.25
# -- For row
row = cm.ax_row_dendrogram.get_position()
cm.ax_row_dendrogram.set_position([row.x0, row.y0, row.width*1.1, row.height]) #row.width*4

#set the label for xaxis
cm.ax_heatmap.set_xlabel("Cells",fontsize=15) 

#set the label for yaxis
cm.ax_heatmap.set_ylabel("Molecules",fontsize=15)
#cm.ax_heatmap.set_yticklabels(Data.iloc[:,0])
cm.ax_heatmap.set_yticklabels(final)

# -- dpi is for resolution
cm.savefig('Demo_final.pdf', dpi = 2000)


#cm.fig
```

The output is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ww/PycharmProjects/Demo.py", line 65, in <module>
    final.append(actual[int(lis[i])-1])
  File "/Users/ww/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 601, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/Users/ww/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2428, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 98, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/_libs/index.c:4363)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 106, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/_libs/index.c:4046)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5085)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 756, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:13913)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 762, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:13857)
KeyError: -1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please describe clearly what you expect `final.append(actual[int(lis[i])-1])` to do. Since `actual` is a dataframe you may need to access its values differently; but in order to help you one would need to know what the purpose of that code line would be.